# I can not run any Windows 11 VM on my Windows 11

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I have AMD 3800x with SVM enabled and I tried to run Win 11 VM using VMWare and Virtual Box without any success.

VMWare display error

> Virtualized AMD-V/RVI is not supported on this platform.
>
> Continue without virtualized AMD-V/RVI?

Although it was not appearing before. And Virtual Box the VM image load very slow and then stop.

Hyper-v is disabled so I dont know what I can do ?

Comment: A quick Google search tells me your CPU does not support AMD-V (v is for virtualization) [cite](https://www.amd.com/en/product/8441), and the technology is required by hypervisors, the warning message you have given seems to confirm that, so I guess you need a new CPU, but I may be wrong...

Comment: "Although it was not appearing before." - Please provide more details.

Comment: When I created the VM first time it run normally on VMWare then one day this error message start to appear and still like this for months now.

Comment: Do you recollect if Windows 11 Host OS updated itself just before that error started to appear?

Comment: @patkim yes Windows 11 updated. I tried yesterday with fresh copy from Microsoft but for virtual box but when I try to open it it hangup.

Answer (score 0):

The
[AMD Ryzen 7 3800X](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Zen/AMD-Ryzen%207%203800X.html)
supports AMD-V / AMD Virtualization technology.
Since you enabled SVM in the BIOS, you might have not enabled vitualization
in Windows.

To check, run Task Manager, Performance tab, CPU section,
where on the bottom right you can see if "Virtualization" is Enabled
or Disabled.

If Disabled, run the "Turn Windows features on or off" and
disable "Virtual Machine Platform" but enable
"Windows Hypervisor Platform".
Click OK and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Tried now and Hyper-V not checked but still same error.

Comment: What is your motherboard? Are you using the latest BIOS?

Comment: Yes last bios Version 4403 TUF GAMING X570-PLUS (WI-FI). I updated my bios severla times while I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn Off core isolation memory integrity in Windows Security.
2. Enable Virtualisation in BIOS.
3. Turn off Hypervisor from program and settings.

I am able to run VWware workstation in windows 11 home with AMD-V / AMD Virtualisation.

Answer (score -1):

Virtualized AMD-V/RVI is not supported on this platform.
Continue without virtualized AMD-V/RVI?
On Windows 11, GNS3 v2.2.34, VMware Player 16
Solution:
Check Task Manager - Performance tab - Virtualization is enabled.
Control Panel - All Control Panel Items - Programs and Features - Turn Windows Features On or OF - Uncheck Virtual Machine Platform & Windows Hypervisor Platform

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).